# Why is my terminal returning this s3 error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here's the error I keep receiving:

```
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

I've triple-checked my credentials and googled this error to my wits' end. I edited my bucket policy to add an s3:ListBucket action, but to no avail. When I do so, it just returns a similar message:

```
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

This is also my first time creating an s3 bucket so it's quite possible I missed some important step.

I have triple-checked my keys and even tried creating an additional user (editing the bucket permissions to allow for authenticated users). Always returns the same error.

Comment: I would start again from scratch, with a new bucket and a new IAM user. Don't add any policy to the bucket. Instead add an S3 policy to your IAM user (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-s3 for an example). Then set your  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables for the IAM user's access key and secret key, then use the awscli to invoke 'aws s3 ls s3://mybucket'.

Comment: Could you show us your policy (Bucket Policy and appropriate IAM policy)?

Answer (score 16):

I found this question after I was getting the same (2nd) error as you:

```
$ aws s3 ls

A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

It turns out that there is a [specific policy permission](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html) that you need to add to be able to list all the available buckets:

```
{
    "Sid": "AllowListingOfAllBuckets",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    ]
},
```

As you don't state which command you were running to generate the error, I can't say whether this will be helpful to the OP, but hopefully it will help someone else who stumbles upon this post in the same situation as me.

Answer (score 7):

I had a very similar problem. My user had S3FullPermissions and I could create buckets and list all of them:

```
aws s3 mb s3://my-bucket
make_bucket: s3://my-bucket/

aws s3 ls
2017-03-24 12:30:34 my-bucket
```

But when I tried to run:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

The error itself was related with the **awscli version** I was using and not with any misconfiguration of my buckets/users/policies. To solve it, I **removed the awscli package** installed from my distro repository **and installed it using pip**:

```
# apt-get remove awscli
# pip install awscli
```

Hope this help someone in a similar situation, I have wasted several hours trying to guess what was going on here.

Comment: what's the problematic version here ?