# boto3: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I get this error in terminal when I try to list all the buckets using boto3: `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied`.

Here's the code:

```
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

I found a stack overflow question ([Why is my terminal returning this s3 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319678/why-is-my-terminal-returning-this-s3-error)) and below is the proposed solution. I'm very unfamiliar with AWS so I need a bit of guidance.

Where can I find the dictionary inside like the one below inside the AWS console?

```
{
"Sid": "AllowListingOfAllBuckets",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
    "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
],
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::*"
]
}
```

Comment: S3 console, select the bucket and view the properties. Add a bucket policy. Alternatively, set those permissions on the IAM user or role your Boto3 code is using.

Answer (score 1):

you may add the following to the Actions array in the policy:
`s3:ListBucket`

```
{
    "Sid": "AllowListingOfAllBuckets",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
       "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
       "s3:ListBuckets",
    ],
    "Resource": [
       "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    ]
}
```

You may need to update the Resource:
`"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mywebsite.media/*"`