# Permission issues with: listing s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3

What permission do I need to change to allow listing all s3 buckets?

I can run: `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname;`
but I cannot run: `aws s3 ls;`

The bucket policy is this:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [

        {
            "Sid": "Sid",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::6666666:user/myuser"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my terminal returning this s3 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319678/why-is-my-terminal-returning-this-s3-error)

Answer (score 0):

Credit due from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35746318/1242581

I needed the `ListAllMyBuckets` action on my user or user's group:

```
{
    "Sid": "AllowListingOfAllBuckets",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    ]
}
```