# Total size of folder in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a nested "folder"/object structure in my S3 bucket:

```
myBucket/level1/level2/file1.txt
myBucket/level1/level2/file2.txt
...
```

Is there any way with `aws s3 ls` or `aws s3api` to list the size of each "folder"/object on level2?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use boto3, take a look at my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58220730/9931092

Comment: You might want to use this https://serverfault.com/a/644795/423320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://myBucket/level1/level2/ --recursive --summarize | awk 'BEGIN{ FS= " "} /Total Size/ {print $3}'
```

It will print the sum of the sizes, in bytes, of all files under `level2`.