# How I can get list of objects from S3 bucket via aws lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have problem with AWS lambda, when I trying to get list of objects from S3 bucket. I amd doing it via boto3 paginator:

[image]

but I cannot to receive the data from paginator as results. Tricky is that I can do it on local machine, but when I try to do this via deployed aws lambda - it is just gone to the time out.

Comment: your bucket and lambda both are in same region?

Comment: Does lambda has permissions to access S3 or are you in private subnet?

Comment: yes, they both in the same region

Comment: @Marcin yes, they both in one private subnet

Comment: @ppostnov If private subnet, does your lambda have permissions to use private subnet? If yes, do you use VPN gateway to access S3 or have NAT setup?

Comment: This might be helpfull - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58220730/9931092

Comment: If it's timing out my guess is you need an S3 VPC endpoint, since you say the lambda's in a private subnet. Without the endpoint you will get a timeout as opposed to some other kind of error (assuming there isn't internet access via a NAT gateway or something).

Comment: @marcin I have direct connect vpc + 2 privat subnet + one security group

Comment: @404 I have direct connect vpc + 2 privat subnet + one security group

Comment: yes, it indeed related to my current vcp settings, because  a lambda works properly without it.

Comment: any suggestions ? )

Comment: @ppostnov If you don't have an S3 endpoint in your VPC, add one in and see if that sorts it.

Comment: @404 if you mean endpoint like this com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3, then I already have it

Comment: Hi @ppostnov, ensure that your private subnets have internet access ( through nat gateway is a possibility ) or as 404 mention you can use  and s3 endpoint in your vpc ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html )

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I was the same problem and what worked for me is to give to Lambda policy that have the access to S3 you can see the following guide on how to do it:

https://www.anblicks.com/blog/10-step-guide-to-configure-s3-bucket-with-a-lambda-function-using-sqs

And also to increase the time out of Lambda from 3 seconds to more